# ¿ Cómo puedo obtener el valor de un select y llevarlo hacia una celda de tabla html?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, html-tabla

necesito algo de ayuda.
Necesito obtener el valor de un select y llevarlo hacia una celda de tabla html.
De momento tengo esto. Al ejecutar el programa el select envia sólo el valor de las opciones(valor **1**), pero yo necesito que el select me envie a la tabla, el contenido de las opciones (contenido **articulo 1**)

```js
 var names=document.getElementsByName('datos[]');
function InsertRow()
{
  var TableRow="<tr></tr>";
 for(key=0; key < names.length; key++)
    TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + names[key].value + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);

  var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
 TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
 document.getElementById("tbl1").appendChild(TrElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<label>Fecha:</label><input type="date" name="datos[]">
<label>Articulo:</label>
<select name="datos[]">
   <option selected disabled>Articulos</option>
   <option value="1">Articulo 1</option> 
   <option value="2">Articulo 2</option> 
</select>


<button onclick="InsertRow()">Insertar a tabla
</button>

 <table id=tbl1>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Fecha</th>
         <th>Articulo</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
        
     </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 
 

</body>
</html>
```

En mi proyecto similar a este,hago uso de datepicker y no date de html, y no tengo problema con ello, sin embargo sólo estoy teniendo problemas con el select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tengo una solucion a tu codigo pero el problema es que estas usando el mismo name[] para diferentes etiquetas (input y select) las cuales hacen conflicto y se debe diferenciar cuando estas poblando la tabla para que sepa usar el metodo indicado para el select y obtener el nombre.

Este es el codigo que he adicionado a la funcion InserRow()

```
var combo = document.getElementsByName('datos[]')[1]; // codigo
                var selected = (key==1)? 
combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text : names[key].value;
```

(especifica cual es el `select` par tomar el texto y sigue con el `value` para el `input`).

Adjunto el código en *JavaScript* / *HTML*.

```js
  var names=document.getElementsByName('datos[]');

        function InsertRow()
        {
        var TableRow="<tr></tr>";
            for(key=0; key < names.length; key++) {
                var combo = document.getElementsByName('datos[]')[1]; // cpdigo
                var selected = (key==1)? combo.options[combo.selectedIndex].text : names[key].value; 
                TableRow = TableRow.substring(0,TableRow.length-5) + "<td>" + selected + "</td>" + TableRow.substring(TableRow.length-5);
             }
        var TrElement = document.createElement("tr");
            TrElement.innerHTML = TableRow;
            document.getElementById("tbl1").appendChild(TrElement);
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<label>Fecha:</label><input type="date" name="datos[]">
<label>Articulo:</label>
<select name="datos[]">
   <option selected disabled>Articulos</option>
   <option value="1">Articulo 1</option> 
   <option value="2">Articulo 2</option> 
</select>


<button onclick="InsertRow()">Insertar a tabla
</button>

 <table id=tbl1>
 <thead>
     <tr>
         <th>Fecha</th>
         <th>Articulo</th>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
        
     </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 

</body>
</html>
```

EL RESULTADO:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alexander, muchas gracias.. era exactamente lo que necesitaba. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Rodrígez ¿ hay alguna forma de poder dejar los name por separados , tanto del calendario y del select ?

Comment: Si se puede pero tendrias que cambiar toda la logica del bucle for() en en el JavaScript porque este es el que se encarga de hacer el recorrido a los names, dar los valores para agregar el cuerpo para nueva fila <tr> elemento <table>, en cierta forma seria mas facil porque no haces el recorrido para obtener los valores names para datos[]